# JavaScriptSerializer is subtracting one day from date

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, javascriptserializer

I am using `JavaScriptSerializer` for serializing DateTime, but when I deserialize it show one day less from the date it get serialize:

Here is test:

```
  DateTime startDate=new DateTime(2012,1,20);//set the 20th of January
  JavaScriptSerializer  serializer=new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string serializeDate= serializer.Serialize(startDate);
  DateTime afterDeserialize= serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(serializeDate);//I get 19th of Jan
  Assert.Equals(startDate, afterDeserialize);
```

firstly I thougt it because of javascript datetime format but as I know for javascript Month is zero index `0=January`, but I am getting one day less than the original date.

Comment: Solution 1: muck around with timezones, etc. Solution 2: just store the year, month and day as separate values, then recombine after deserialization.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not losing a day arbitrarily, it's converting to a UTC date (or I should say using the date in a UTC date format) so when it's unserialized it you're no longer within your personal time zone. It's basically performing:

```
DateTime whateverDate = /* incoming date */;
long ticks = whateverDate.ToUniversalTime() // make UTC
  .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))       // subtract UNIX Epoch
  .TotalMilliseconds();                     // get milliseconds since then
// push in to the "\/Date(ticks)\/" format
String value = String.Format(@"\/Date({0})\/", ticks);
```

However, try the following:

```
// or you rely on it serializing, then bring it back to your own local time
// (apply the time zone).
afterDeserialize = afterDeserialize.ToLocalTime();
```

You'll now have the UTC time back to your local time (with time zone applied).

---

To Pass your test:

```
DateTime startDate              = new DateTime(2012,1,20);
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String serializeDate            = serializer.Serialize(startDate);
DateTime afterDeserialize       = serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(serializeDate)
                                  .ToLocalTime(); // Note: this is added

Assert.Equals(startDate, afterDeserialize); // pass!
```

Comment: This is the [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_topic2), albeit very unclear.

Comment: DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 20).ToUniversalTime(); it sets the startDate to 19 jan? and on deserialize getting the same... Why it is happening?

Comment: http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/02/serializing-datetime-values-using.html  Here is a blog explaining the problem quite in detail

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed - it's changing the timezone. There's an implicit midnight attached to your date, so your are probably losing a few hours in the timezone shift, causing the date to change.

Comment: My timezone is PST, how can I input and get output in the same timezone.

Comment: This - and many other reasons - are why you should use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) instead of the `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed - Consider using a `DateTimeOffset` and serialize in ISO8601 format instead, using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) instead of the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by using

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()
```

instead of

```
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize().
```

The latter call stores your DateTime converted to some random timezone (GMT+0 seems to be hardcoded).

Answer (score 2):

On deserializing `JavaScriptSerializer` giving me output in `UTC (Universal Time)` which due to change in hours change the date. As `Brad Christie` suggested to change DateTime to UTC it can solve the problems.

But actually there is no need to change the:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 20).ToUniversalTime();
```

as it is already taking it as Universal Time. So I just convert the output of deserialize to `LocalTime`:

```
 DateTime afterDeserialize= serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(serializeDate);
 afterDeserialize.ToLocalTime();
```

it solved the issue.

Comment: Funny, was just in the middle of typing that up in an update to my answer. ;-)

Comment: :), marked your answer correct, and just put this here, so it helps others