# DayLight Saving Time issue of DateTime from JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize to ToLocalTime

Tags: c#, datetime, dst, javascriptserializer

[Previously I was facing this issue and solved as described in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003335/javascriptserializer-is-subtracting-one-day-from-date).

Currently after DayLight Saving implementation I observed the issue that if I am selecting

```
 DateTime startDate=new DateTime(2012,1,20); //Eastern Timezone (UTC -5:00)
```

after serializing it would convert it to:

```
string serializeDate= serializer.Serialize(startDate); //In ticks 20-Jan 2012 05:00AM
```

on deserializing and `ToLocalTime()`

```
DateTime afterDeserialize= serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(serializeDate);
afterDeserialize.ToLocalTime();
```

It was working perfect until:

> [image: datetime zone]

I unchecked the `Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time`.

Now its on serialization add `4:00 hours` (due to Daylight Saving Time) but on `ToLocalTime()` subtracting `-5:00 hours` due to environment daylight saving time which change the date of my object subtracting one day.

How I can inject the current environment Daylight Saving time on both conversion?

Comment: What's the time value in `startTime` when you untick that box? (before serialization).

Comment: in both cases its 20-jan-2012 00:00

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to store the offset for your timezone, then re-apply it after conversion.

To make it dynamic (as you said in comments), you can first get current timezone:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(myDateTime);
```

Then do:

```
DateTime startDate=new DateTime(2012,1,20).Add(offset);
```

Then after serialization:

```
DateTime afterDeserialize= serializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(serializeDate);
afterDeserialize.ToLocalTime().AddOffset(offset);
```

Comment: Nice!!! but how can I make FindSystemTimeZoneById() dynamic. means it automatically select the timezoneinfo for system.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Check my edit, I changed it to use the `CurrentTimeZone` property.

Comment: I updated your code.  The `StandardName` and the `Id` are not the same thing. (`Id` is invariant, `StandardName` is for display and can be localized).  And there's no need to look it up - it's always there in `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.